# Как изменить цвет верхней рамки приложения в Qt designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qmainwindow

Собственно, весь вопрос поместился в названии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот таблица стилей для QMainWindow:

```
background-color: rgb(68, 70, 79);
```

Comment: MIkhail, таблица стилей вам в этом не поможет, надо писать код. Данному вопросу посвящено достаточное количество постов, чтобы изучить тему. Почитайте некоторые из них https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+FramelessWindowHint , попробуйте что-то написать, если что-то не получится поможем. Ключевое слово `FramelessWindowHint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как было указано в комментариях, это не убрать. Верхнюю панель нельзя изменять вообще. Можно только убрать и написать новую.